# Phone not booting up

Tags: system-error

I was using my android device and suddenly it turn off, and when I tried to turn it back on I received [image: This warning screen] then It turn on for couple of minutes and after that it turn off and now the phone is not responding whatsoever, and it's not turning on.........can anyone help me with solving this problem, and I also read the documents from android and found nothing useful regarding this problem, all I found was some explanation about the causes but nothing on how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your software must have been corrupted, I suggest that you GOOGLE instructions on how to re-flash your firmware depending on your device, of course.

Comment: but the phone isn't even booting up now